# Filter an array of NSDate for Today, Yesterday for plotting

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, plot, nsdate

I have an array of journal entries with timestamps.

```
class JournalNoteEntry {
var timeCreated: NSDate?
var value: Int?
var note: String?
}
```

How can I filter this array for entries of Today, Yesterday, This Week, This Month, etc. and plot the my `value` vs. `timeCreated` and label the X-axis

I have searched a lot for this basic need but unable to find answers.

Can someone please help...

Comment: I'd suggest to create an array of start date/enddate for today/yesterday/this week, this month, etc. Then compare.

Comment: have you tried NSPredicate?

Comment: @Larme Thank you for you reply. Could you please post some code

Comment: @iOSDeveloper No, I have no idea about `NSPredicate`. Could you please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are writing in Swift 3, you should use the native Swift's type rather than the Foundation's classes (those that start with `NS...`):

```
class JournalNoteEntry {
    var timeCreated: Date?
    var value: Int?
    var note: String?
}
```

On to your problem: let's write a simple function to filter for all entry between a start and end date:

```
func entries(in journal: [JournalNoteEntry],  from: Date, to: Date) -> [JournalNoteEntry] {
    return journal.filter {
        guard let timeCreated = $0.timeCreated else {
            return false
        }

        // Notice that this is half-open range
        return from <= timeCreated && timeCreated < to
    }
}
```

The majority of your efforts will be on determining the date ranges. One way to do it is via an extension to the `Calendar` class:

```
extension Calendar {
    func todayRange() -> (Date, Date) {
        let startDate = self.startOfDay(for: Date())
        let endDate   = self.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
        return (startDate, endDate)
    }

    func yesterdayRange() -> (Date, Date) {
        let endDate   = self.startOfDay(for: Date())
        let startDate = self.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: endDate)!
        return (startDate, endDate)
    }

    func thisWeekRange() -> (Date, Date) {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.weekday = self.firstWeekday

        let startDate = self.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime, direction: .backward)!
        let endDate   = self.nextDate(after: startDate, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
        return (startDate, endDate)
    }

    func thisMonthRange() -> (Date, Date) {
        var components = self.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month], from: Date())
        components.day = 1

        let startDate = self.date(from: components)!
        let endDate   = self.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: startDate)!

        return (startDate, endDate)
    }
}

// Run this in Playground to see it formatted in your local timezone
// If you call print(), it will always display in UTC
// Assuming today = Nov 7, 2016
Calendar.current.todayRange()       // "Nov 7, 2016, 12:00 AM", "Nov 8, 2016, 12:00 AM"
Calendar.current.yesterdayRange()   // "Nov 6, 2016, 12:00 AM", "Nov 7, 2016, 12:00 AM"
Calendar.current.thisWeekRange()    // "Nov 6, 2016, 12:00 AM", "Nov 13, 2016, 12:00 AM"
Calendar.current.thisMonthRange()   // "Nov 1, 2016, 12:00 AM", "Dec 1, 2016, 12:00 AM"
```

To get all the journal entries within the current month:

```
// journal is an array of JournalNoteEntry
let (startDate, endDate) = Calendar.current.thisMonthRange()
let results = entries(in: journal, from: startDate, to: endDate)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of posting the code. It looks very useful in my case. However, you somehow assumed I am using Swift 3. I am NOT because I need to submit an app next month and don't want to convert all my code into Swift 3. I would highly appreciate it if you can post the code for Swift 2.1.1. You can keep the Swift 3 code which could be helpful for others. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timeCreated == %f", NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
let arrFiltedArray =   array .filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

where timeCreated contain timeIntervalSince1970 for your date, Means convert your datatype from NSDate to double